# Error while trying to run docker redis image on Alpine Linux 3.7.0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, alpine

#### Specifications

---

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
VirtualBox 5.2.8
Alpine Linux Extended 3.7.0
```

#### Docker Info

---

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.10.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 0351df1c5a66838d0c392b4ac4cf9450de844e2d
init version: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574
Kernel Version: 4.9.65-1-hardened
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.7
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.953GiB
Name: node-4
ID: 3AVF:5SGV:6Y3P:HQW4:PTSU:BRA7:R3PL:AW4F:CIFW:BYDY:FY5P:O6GX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

#### Issue Description

---

I'm trying to run the `bitname-redis-docker` image on my `Alpine Linux` setup on VirtualBox.

```
docker run --name redis -e ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes bitnami/redis:latest
```

The container never starts. Inspecting the log it says

```
Welcome to the Bitnami redis container
Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis
Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis/issues
Send us your feedback at containers@bitnami.com

PROT_EXEC|PROT_WRITE failed.
INFO  ==> Starting redis...
sed: can't read /opt/bitnami/redis/conf/redis.conf: No such file or directory
14:C 26 Apr 19:38:43.389 # Fatal error, can't open config file '/opt/bitnami/redis/conf/redis.conf'
```

To further investigate I ran an `strace` and here is the log output [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/CHr9ZHYJ).

Can someone tell me what's going on here? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is an error with Alpine. I re-tried with CentOS and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

One could also use a docker image from an official docker repository like https://hub.docker.com/r/library/redis/

```
docker run --name some-redis -d redis:alpine
```